# Why don't warts caused by HPV spread to the whole body?

Tags: virus

My son had a [plantar wart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantar_wart) on his foot, which (as I understand it) is caused by a virus which only infects skin cells. Once in the skin cell the virus replicates, but when attacked by the immune system prompts the growth of a hard, thick layer of skin (callus). Warts are caused by a [HPV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_papillomavirus).

Given the wart has infected a skin cell, and skin cells are next to each other in a great big sheet covering the entire human body, why is it that we don't become completely covered in wart?  I assume that it's not the immune system keeping the wart at bay, because the original wart isn't defeated and we can get other spot infections elsewhere.

Comment: The Wikipedia page you link to says that they are self-limiting, although it doesn't say why.

Comment: actually there is a person who was completely covered with warts; not as a homogeneous sheet, though. Watched the video on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=renb0qQR7cA).

Answer (score 4):

Plantar warts grow **deep** into the skin and **slowly** <sup>[1]</sup>. It is a common thing for warts to multiply <sup>[1]</sup>, but because of the slow growth speed, their symptoms <sup>[2]</sup> and the self clear-up <sup>[1]</sup> they can't end up by covering the entire skin surface of a previously healthy person.

There are cases of generalized warts in patients with immune deficiency like hypogammaglobulinaemia, impairment of cell mediated immunity <sup>[3]</sup>. The immune system plays an important role in limiting warts. There is also a case of generalized facial warts in a patient with no other known medical condition <sup>[4]</sup>.

References:

1. American College of Foot and Ankle Surgeons, [*Plantar Wart (Verruca Plantaris)*](http://www.foothealthfacts.org/footankleinfo/Plantar_Wart.htm)
2. MAYO Clinic, [*Diseases and Conditions - Plantar warts*](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/plantar-warts/basics/symptoms/con-20025706).
3. Reid TM, Fraser NG, Kernohan IR. [Generalized warts and immune deficiency.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1086679) Br. J. Dermatol. 1976 Nov;95(5):559-64. PubMed PMID: 1086679.
4. Semon H. [Papillomatosis: Generalized Facial Warts.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19990539) Proc. R. Soc. Med. 1935 Dec;29(2):90. PubMed PMID: 19990539.

Comment: Your reference for "self clear-up" only indicates that this is a possibility, not a certainty, and doesn't discuss the mechanism. "Generalized warts and immune deficiency" was informative, and suggests that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antigenic_variation is the cause of subsequent infections.